# QT 5 missing all network support

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I installed the complete QT 5.5.1 offline installation package for OS X. When I create a basic console application in Qt Creator targeting my local system, the network-related includes (such as QNetworkRequest) are missing.

When I search the directory for its location, I get this:

```
Qt5.5.1/5.5/clang_64/lib$ find ./ -name "QString"
.//QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QString
Qt5.5.1/5.5/clang_64/lib$ find ./ -name "QNetworkRequest"
.//QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QNetworkRequest
```

So, the QtNetwork framework/module/plugin (I'm new to QT, so I'm not sure the correct name) is not in scope. I've looked through the project config, but there's nothing that seems obvious/simple and I have a hard time believing that I'll have to add command-line flags to fix this.

If it matters, the "About Plugins..." dialog doesn't have anything with "network" in its name.

I've also heard the word "framework" being thrown around in reference to Mac distributables, but I'm not familiar with Mac application development beyond the stuff that's familiar to most Linux people.

What am I missing? Thanks for the help in advance. I was just trying to finish something up and everything else has been fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually edit your project file and add "network" to the list of frameworks (identified with the "QT" field):

```
QT += core gui network
```

The project-edit screen (where this *should* be) seems a bit simplistic with really only the build-steps being able to be defined there. If anyone can say whether there's a more elegant way to do this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Adding "network" to the config is a elegant as it gets (what's not elegant about it?)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I'm merely pointing out that it's misleading to have a project-edit screen and to expect you to have to update that file by hand before you're even able to write code. After all, we're using an IDE... not the command-line.

Comment: Hmm, to me the build system is like code, so it feels natural and most efficient to me to write that by hand in a text editor. That way the files stay readable (insofar that's possible in any build system...), which one will always have to manually edit anyway when the logic becomes more complex. I wonder if there's a build system/IDE covering 90% in UI and still allowing one to implement the last 10% by hand without the last 10% being impossibly hard.

Comment: Sure, but it'd have to be a structured text file (YAML, XML, JSON, ...). Traditionally, automated processes write everything else poorly. Only a few worthy and responsible individuals have been involved in creating the standards for nice-looking files, but most of the rest of the development world, including those people that happen to be working on IDEs, is comprised of lazy slobs.